# How to retrieve subarray elements in JSON with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON object and I want to parse it with javascript. I am able to get B, A, and 208 but I'm having trouble getting the data from times.

```
{
"room":[
    {"campusName":"B",
    "buildingCode":"A",
    "roomNumber":"208",
    "times":[
            "7-8", "9-10"
    ]
    }
]
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
    $.each(data.room, function(data){
        $("ul").append("<li>campus: "+this['campusName']+"</li><li>building: "+this['buildingCode']+"</li>");
        $.each(data.times, function(){
            $("ul").append("<li>stuff: "+this['times']+"</li>")
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't your times array not contain an object and just strings i.e.: `"times": ["7-8", "9-10"]`? Then this would be your value

Comment: That's invalid JSON as-written

Comment: It's really confusing to use the same variable name `data` in both `$.getJSON` and `$.each`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code for your `JSON`

```
var data = {
"room":[
    {"campusName":"B",
    "buildingCode":"A",
    "roomNumber":"208",
    "times":[
            "7-8", "9-10"
    ]
    }
]
}
```

Then you can use following to get your desire results:

```
data.room[0].campusName; // ==> B
data.room[0].buildingCode; // ==> A
data.room[0].roomNumber; // ==> 208
data.room[0].times; // ==> ["7-8", "9-10"]
```

**EDIT2:**

```
$.each(data.room, function(i) { 
    console.log(data.room[i].campusName);
    console.log(data.room[i].buildingCode );
    console.log(data.room[i].roomNumber );
    console.log(data.room[i].times);
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
B
A
208
["7-8", "9-10"]
```

**EDIT1:**

For more details visit [`JSON` syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) and how to access it.

Comment: What's the difference between this and the JSON in his question?

Comment: It is the same, I just stored it in a variable `data` that's why I written it. Nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `data.times` are just strings, not objects, so you shouldn't index them. It should just be:

```
$.each(data.times, function() {
    $("ul").append("<li>stuff: " + this + "</li>");
});
```

Also, the argument list in your first `$.each()` callback is wrong. It should be `function(i, data)` -- the first argument is the array index (or object property name if you're iterating over an object), the second argument is the value.

```js
var data = {
  "room": [{
    "campusName": "B",
    "buildingCode": "A",
    "roomNumber": "208",
    "times": [
      "7-8", "9-10"
    ]
  }]
};

$.each(data.room, function(i, data) {
  $("ul").append("<li>campus: " + this['campusName'] + "</li><li>building: " + this['buildingCode'] + "</li>");
  $.each(data.times, function() {
    $("ul").append("<li>stuff: " + this + "</li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: the problem was in your argument list of the outer iteration function. See the updated answer.